# Corona build with Application Loader, different errors for different build settings

Tags: xcode, coronasdk

I am having trouble with submitting an app via the application loader.
I have written the app with Corona SDK. It is already available on Google Play but XCode is giving me errors...
During development, I have been testing the app on my personal iPhone with a developers provisioning profile from my private account. Now I want to publish it with the company profile. But I can't.
The errors I receive vary. If I build for Device, and click on the popupped "would you like to upload to appstore?" I get this Error:
This app containts an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID ***********

If I instead build for Xcode Simulator and try and upload that zip file instead I get these errors:

The Coderesources file is missing and it must me a symbolic _CodeSignature/CodeResources. Make certain that the bundle is on a locally-mounted volume (not a remote SMB volume) and be certain to use the mac os x finder to compress it.

Iphone Ipod Touch: application executable contains unsopported architecture(s): i386

Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure myAPP is a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned.

I have been trying to make new profiles and certificates all weekend, but thats hasn't helped.
My question is Which errors should I try to fix? If theses errors only appear on different builds?

Is there any good templates for Build.Settings so that i can know for sure that its not my settings file thats corrupt?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifying your BundleID in build.settings? If so, do you need to? If not, take it out. If so and you have the actual app ID in there try removing it so it's just com.appname.yourname as you specified in iTunes Connect when creating your provisioning profile.

Comment: Thank for trying to help me Peach! I figured it out after uploading it on my own account. It was just That I was only Team Admin and not Team Agent. sigh... Thanks anyway.